# How to select specific <option> tags in jQuery to transform into a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, cheerio

I want to get the information below the first `<option>` tag, I want to use jQuery/Cheerio to extract the information and transform the end result into a dictionary. It would ideally look like this

```js
const info = {
   '5.5':12773,
   '6':12774,
}
```

And it goes on till the end.

```html
<select name="size_attribute[size]" id="attributesize-size_uswomen" class="size-attribute-select">
  <option>Choose Your Size</option>
  <option value="12773" source="16004">5.5</option>
  <option value="12774" source="16006">6</option>
  <option value="12775" source="16008">6.5</option>
  <option value="14805" source="16010">7</option>
  <option value="14809" source="16012">7.5</option>
  <option value="12749" source="16014">8</option>
  <option value="14816" source="16016">8.5</option>
  <option value="14820" source="16018">9</option>
  <option value="14824" source="16020">9.5</option>
  <option value="15175" source="16022">10</option>
  <option value="15178" source="16024">10.5</option>
  <option value="15184" source="16028">11.5</option>
  <option value="15187" source="16030">12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @SMAKSS I am trying to implement your solution in Cheerio, and currently receiving this error (SyntaxError: unmatched pseudo-class :first)

Comment: Well, cheerio does not support the `:first` pseudo-selector and my provided answer will work with jQuery alone, but to fix it I suggest another approach which could be useful,

Comment: Did you come up with a conclusion?

Comment: @SMAKSS Yes it worked well

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want to do all of this in jQuery, you can simply get all of the `option`s of a `select` element with the jQuery selector *(`$('#attributesize-size_uswomen option')`)* and then perform a for loop *([`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/))* over it and fill your object easily.

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
var opts = $('#attributesize-size_uswomen option:not(:first)');
var info = {};

$.each(opts, function(index, opt) {
   info[$(opt).text()] = parseInt($(opt).val())
});

console.log(info);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="size_attribute[size]" id="attributesize-size_uswomen" class="size-attribute-select">
  <option>Choose Your Size</option>
  <option value="12773" source="16004">5.5</option>
  <option value="12774" source="16006">6</option>
  <option value="12775" source="16008">6.5</option>
  <option value="14805" source="16010">7</option>
  <option value="14809" source="16012">7.5</option>
  <option value="12749" source="16014">8</option>
  <option value="14816" source="16016">8.5</option>
  <option value="14820" source="16018">9</option>
  <option value="14824" source="16020">9.5</option>
  <option value="15175" source="16022">10</option>
  <option value="15178" source="16024">10.5</option>
  <option value="15184" source="16028">11.5</option>
  <option value="15187" source="16030">12</option>
</select>
```

**NOTE:** Since the `opt` itself in the loop will be a regular object to use the jQuery functions over it you need to make a jQuery object with `$()` operand otherwise you can use it as regular NODE object and get its properties with javascript built-in properties like [`text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement), [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or `value`.

### UPDATE

Since you receive an error in the implementation with cheerio which [does not support `:first`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/575) pseudo-selector, so you can select all of the options then exclude the first one in the object creation.

```js
var opts = $('#attributesize-size_uswomen option');
var info = {};

$.each(opts, function(index, opt) {
  if (index != 0)
    info[$(opt).text()] = parseInt($(opt).val())
});

console.log(info);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="size_attribute[size]" id="attributesize-size_uswomen" class="size-attribute-select">
  <option>Choose Your Size</option>
  <option value="12773" source="16004">5.5</option>
  <option value="12774" source="16006">6</option>
  <option value="12775" source="16008">6.5</option>
  <option value="14805" source="16010">7</option>
  <option value="14809" source="16012">7.5</option>
  <option value="12749" source="16014">8</option>
  <option value="14816" source="16016">8.5</option>
  <option value="14820" source="16018">9</option>
  <option value="14824" source="16020">9.5</option>
  <option value="15175" source="16022">10</option>
  <option value="15178" source="16024">10.5</option>
  <option value="15184" source="16028">11.5</option>
  <option value="15187" source="16030">12</option>
</select>
```

Or if you want to keep up with the supported Cheerio approach you use this one:

```js
var info = {};

$('#attributesize-size_uswomen').children().slice(1).each(function() {
  info[$(this).text()] = parseInt($(this).val())
});

console.log(info);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="size_attribute[size]" id="attributesize-size_uswomen" class="size-attribute-select">
  <option>Choose Your Size</option>
  <option value="12773" source="16004">5.5</option>
  <option value="12774" source="16006">6</option>
  <option value="12775" source="16008">6.5</option>
  <option value="14805" source="16010">7</option>
  <option value="14809" source="16012">7.5</option>
  <option value="12749" source="16014">8</option>
  <option value="14816" source="16016">8.5</option>
  <option value="14820" source="16018">9</option>
  <option value="14824" source="16020">9.5</option>
  <option value="15175" source="16022">10</option>
  <option value="15178" source="16024">10.5</option>
  <option value="15184" source="16028">11.5</option>
  <option value="15187" source="16030">12</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieved using `$("select option:not(:first)").each`

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/eYzvZpj)